# Regular expression - match strings between range

Tags: php, regex, expression

I have a string which looks like this:

```
UPDATE id = :id, password = :password;
```

I want to match this string:

```
id = :id, password = :password
```

I wrote this regexp:

```
UPDATE\s(\S+\s*=\s*\S+)\s
```

but it matches only

```
id = :id,
```

I tried also this regexp:

```
UPDATE\s(\S+\s*=\s*\S+)\s;
```

but it cannot recognize a range what I want to match

How I have to define range in the right way to match that what I want?

I will be grateful for any advice.

Comment: I want to match whole string which looks like this "value = :value, test=:value2" from any string, spaces must be allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If input string is always a similar UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE\s*\K|([^;]+)
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/wA3qI5/1)

Comment: What if I want to match: " value = :value, test=:value2" from this string: "INSERT INTO table (value, value1) VALUES (:value1, :value2,) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = :value, test=:value2;" ?

Comment: I figured out how to make this. This regexp resolve my problem: UPDATE\s(.+,*?);

Comment: Just remove the alternation `UPDATE\s*\K([^;]+)` @MateuszRavage